# Python error: RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem. Try running as root! (tried all of the suggestions)

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have updated the code to look like this:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import datetime

BUTTON_PIN = 16
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)


class TimedButton:
    def __init__(self, pin, callback, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP, package=None):
        """
        A TimedButton initiates a callback after a button has been pressed and then released.  It passes the duration
        the button was pressed to the callback
        :param pin: pin the button is on
        :param callback: callback to call when pressed
        :param pull_up_down: indicates the button is pulled up or down with a resistor
        :param package: package to pass to the callback
        """
        self.pin = pin
        self.package = package
        self.last_push = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.callback = callback
        self.press_time = None
        GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=pull_up_down)
        GPIO.add_event_detect(pin, edge=GPIO.BOTH, callback=self._debounce_function)

    def _debounce_function(self, pin):
        """
        This function debounces the button.  Buttons are inherently noisy (they ring when pressed)  This function waits
        a period of time before declaring the button to have settled into the current state.
        :param pin: pin the button is on
        :return: None
        """
        time_now = datetime.datetime.now()
        current_state = GPIO.input(self.pin)
        if (time_now - self.last_push).microseconds > .1 * units.microseconds_per_second:
            if current_state and self.press_time is not None:
                self.callback(pin, datetime.datetime.now() - self.press_time, self.package)
            else:
                self.press_time = datetime.datetime.now()
        self.last_push = time_now

def button_callback(pin, state, argument):
    print('{} Pin {} now at {}.  Message:{}'.format(datetime.datetime.now(), pin, state, argument))

def main():
    import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
    print('Starting test_Button')
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN)
    TimedButton(pin=BUTTON_PIN, callback=button_callback)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I have tried:

- sudoing as root
- running as root
- changing ownership of /dev/mem
- reinstalling rpi.gpio

I always get the same error:
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!

Here is what I have tried:
(as pi):

```
pi@snail-patrol:python3 test.py
Starting test_Button
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 49, in main
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
```

(su to root - note tried su without the - also)

```
pi@snail-patrol:sudo su -
root@snail-patrol:/home/pi/temp# python3 test.py
Starting test_Button
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 49, in main
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!

(sudo)
pi@snail-patrol:sudo python3 test.py
Starting test_Button
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 56, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 49, in main
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
```

Here is what the permissions look like

```
pi@snail-patrol:ls -l /dev/mem
crw-r----- 1 root kmem 1, 1 Jul 17 20:56 /dev/mem
pi@snail-patrol:ls -l test.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 pi pi 2110 Jul 18 17:01 test.p
```

Note that I also tried:

```
sudo rpi-update
sudo reboot
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo adduser pi gpio
sudo chown root.gpio /dev/mem && sudo chmod g+rw /dev/mem
```

And I still get the same error!

Comment: Have you checked this out? https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root

Comment: It helps if you show us both your code and the specific commands you've tried to run it.

Comment: I tried @Axiumin_'s suggestion from here: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40105/access-gpio-pins-without-root-no-access-to-dev-mem-try-running-as-root to no avail.

Comment: I also added all of the code as suggested by @larsks

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is misleading. It doesn't actually have anything to do with permissions on `/dev/mem`. It's actually because you're calling `GPIO.remove_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN)` before setting up up the pin.

Consider the following code:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

BUTTON_PIN = 16

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.remove_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)

print('current value of pin', BUTTON_PIN, 'is', GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN))
```

This fails with the same error as your code:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# python test_error.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_error.py", line 6, in <module>
    GPIO.remove_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN)
RuntimeError: No access to /dev/mem.  Try running as root!
```

If we swap the position of the `GPIO.setup` and `GPIO.remove_event_detect` calls, so that we have:

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

BUTTON_PIN = 16

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(BUTTON_PIN, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.remove_event_detect(BUTTON_PIN)

print('current value of pin', BUTTON_PIN, 'is', GPIO.input(BUTTON_PIN))
```

It runs without any error:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# python test_error.py
('current value of pin', 16, 'is', 1)
```

If we rewrite your `main` function so that it looks like this:

```
def main():
    TimedButton(pin=BUTTON_PIN, callback=button_callback)
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
```

Everything works without error. This is the result of me grounding the pin a few times while your code runs:

```
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# python testgpio.py
2020-07-19 16:48:31.000582 Pin 16 now at 0:00:01.313176.  Message:None
2020-07-19 16:48:34.187487 Pin 16 now at 0:00:01.178778.  Message:None
```

There's no reason to call `GPIO.remove_event_detect` at this point in your code, because you haven't set up any event detection. There's also no reason to have that `import` statement in your `main` function, since you're alreadying `import`-ing `RPI.GPIO` at the top of your code.